# Read only the last 3 characters from the end of a file and save them as an int

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to write a function which should read the last three characters from a certain .txt file and return me the value as int.

example of what the file contains:"***** ***** 505" .

when I run the code the function returns me "505" but also gives me "/377? below. 
I noticed a similar existing post yet I was not able to resolve the issue I am looking for a bit more help.

function:

```
int readClientiD(){
    FILE *fp;
     char ch;
     int num=4;
     long length;

     fp = fopen("ClientList.txt", "r");
     if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("cannot open this file");
        exit(1);
     }

     fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
     length = ftell(fp);
     fseek(fp, (length - num), SEEK_SET);

     do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
         cout<< ch;
     } while (ch != EOF);
     cout<<endl;
     fclose(fp);
     return(0);
}
```

Comment: You print `ch` before checking if it's `EOF` or not.

Comment: ch is printed while it is different from EOF.

Comment: No, you print it immediately after reading, and **then** if it was `EOF`, the loop stops.

Comment: can you write me how the code should be if possible?

Comment: If you have already done a seek to the end of the file, why bother with the do-while loop? Why not just a for loop

Comment: for ( ch != EOF )  {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        putchar(ch);
    };
    like this?

Comment: Try `for ( ; ; ) { ch = fgetc (fp); if (ch == EOF) break; cout << ch; }`

Comment: @PaulSanders thank you. it worked

Comment: @PaulSanders alternatively: `while ( (ch = fgetc (fp)) != EOF ) { cout << ch; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is the answer, I think it's better post it as an answer than leave it here, for anyone who will come across this topic.

Comment: @KorelK ok, I've done so now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out the value of `ch` immediately after reading it and before you check it for `EOF`.  You need to do the check first.

```cpp
do {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    cout << ch;
} while (true);
```

Or:

```cpp
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    cout << ch;
}
```

Whether a `char` is signed or unsigned is *unspecified* in the C and C++ standards, so it is up to the compiler implementation to decide. `EOF` is defined as having a negative value, which is *usually* `-1` in most implementations.  When `-1` is treated as an unsigned `char`, it has a value of decimal `255`, hex `0xFF`, **octal `377`**, which means `char` is likely unsigned on your system.